# Single linkedlist creation in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct list
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
struct list *next;
};
struct list* addlistele(struct list*,int,int,int);
/* List c element */
void listc()
{
printf(" soon...\n");
}

void printlist(list)
{
struct list* temp;
temp=list;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
printf("a:%d,b;%d,c:%d\n",temp->a,temp->b,temp->c);
temp=temp->next;
}
}
/* List element  */
struct list* addlistele(struct list* listadd,int b,int d,int m)
{
int i;
struct list* temp;
struct list* addelement=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
addelement->a=b;
addelement->b=d;
addelement->c=m;
addelement->next=NULL;
if(listadd==NULL)
 {
 printf("entering");
 return addelement;
 }
else
{
temp=listadd;
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
temp=temp->next;
}
temp->next=addelement;
} 
return listadd;
}
int main()
{
int ch,i,a,b,c;
struct list *element,*list;
element=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
printf("Choose any one of the option \n");
printf("1.List All \n 2.List c \n");
scanf("%d",&ch);
switch(ch)
{
case 1:printf("Enter values \n");
   for(i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
   scanf("%d %d %d \n",&a,&b,&c);
   list=addlistele(element,a,b,c);
   }
   printlist(list);

   break;
  case 2:listc(); break;
  default:break;
  }
  }
```

Hi all, i have written the code like the above one.In that when i gave inputs

```
> Choose any one of the option 
> 1.List All 
>  2.List c  1 Enter values  2 3 4 1 2 3

The output is
a:0,b;0,c:0
a:2,b;3,c:4
a:1,b;2,c:3
```

and also it is not adding the element first i mean it is not entering into this loop

```
if(listadd==NULL)
     {
     printf("entering");
     return addelement;
     }
```

how to make the head element to be NULL and also i don't know how 0 is coming first.Could anybody can tell me what will be the issue?

Comment: Run it in debugger and you will immediately see it.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` you create head element and pass it to the `addlistele()` function.

```
element=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
...
list=addlistele(element,a,b,c);
```

You are seeing this first element which does not have valid values that you expected.

Solution would be you `malloc()` the element in the function rather than in `main()` and do not allocate `element` in `main()`.

Comment: I have tried that but still it is showing like output Choose any one of the option 
1.List All 
 2.List c 
1
Enter values 
2
3
4
1
2
3



a:0,b;0,c:0
a:1,b;2,c:3

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
struct list *element,*list;
element=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

with

```
struct list *list=NULL;
```

then

replace

```
list=addlistele(element,a,b,c);
```

with

```
list=addlistele(list,a,b,c);
```

Also

replace

```
void printlist(list)
```

with

```
void printlist(struct list *list)
```

and

replace `scanf("%d %d %d \n",&a,&b,&c);` with `scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);`

Comment: Solved the Issue...Thank u so much,,